# I use stand SQL API (DB-Library) to connect SQLSERVER, but I found it generates a memory overflow

Tags: c++

```
            strcpy(sSqlStr, " execute JZJY_batchorder ");
            _ltoa(m_iSHSQLREC_NUM, sValue, 10);
            strcat(sSqlStr, sValue);
            strcat(sSqlStr, ",");
            _ltoa(iBatchCnt, sValue, 10);
            strcat(sSqlStr, sValue);
            strcat(sSqlStr, ",'");
            strcat(sSqlStr, sBatchOrder);
            strcat(sSqlStr, "'");

            m_sqlSHWT.sql_exec_cont(sSqlStr);
            iRet = m_sqlSHWT.sql_begin_getrows();
```

I have to use the stand SQL API, but it generates a memory overflow.

Comment: You should also show how you allocate `sSqlStr`, `sValues` and `sBatchOrder`.

Comment: char sValue[101] = "", sBatchOrder[4097] = "", sSqlStr[4200] = "";

Comment: And where do you get the overflow (full stack)?

Comment: I just simply call the two interfaces, make sure the stored procedure is carried out. after a long time run, the program will appear out of memory

Comment: That would be a *memory leak* not a memory overflow, wouldn't it? Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or something similar to track it down